# Design Patterns in C++: What is the best way to implement an interface with a generic type?

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I would like to use a generic interface that has been implemented.

I have two classes as such:

```
class App {
  MainWindow<State> mainWindow;

  protected:
    virtual MainWindow<State> provideMainWindow() = 0;

  public:
    void exec(){
      // Do something with MainWindow<State>
    }

};

template<class StateType>
class MainWindow {
  protected:
    virtual StateType provideState() = 0;
};
```

Then, I implement the classes as such:

```
class ExampleMainWindow : public MainWindow<ExampleMainWindowState> {
  protected:
    ExampleMainWindowState provideState() override{
      return ExampleMainWindowState();
    }
};

class ExampleApp : public App {
  protected:
    MainWindow<State> provideMainWindow() override {
      // Here is where I'm noticing the difficulty in using the abstract class
      return static_cast<MainWindow<State>>(ExampleMainWindow());
    }

}
```

The compiler tells me that it cannot allocate an abstract class. I tried using pointers, but I couldn't find a way using pointers, either, as new errors began to show up; the compiler wouldn't let me try redefining everything to use pointers such that I could use `dynamic_cast<MainWindow<State*>*>(new ExampleMainWindow())`, either, even though that would be a bit messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is a value-oriented language, in the sense that variables and return values work by-value, not by-reference as in more dynamic languages such as Java or TypeScript. A variable of type `A` cannot hold a value of type `B` even if there's an inheritance relationship `class B: public A`. After all, a `B` value might contain additional data that does not fit into a memory location that was sized to hold `A` values. C++ will silently forget about the extra parts (“[object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)”) which will lead to unexpected behaviour.

To make size irrelevant, you *must* use some kind of pointer. Raw pointers are difficult to use correctly, so let's try a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead.

This code does not work as expected because `MainWindow` and `ExampleMainWindow` are different types:

```cpp
MainWindow<State> provideMainWindow() {
    return ExampleMainWindow();
}
```

Instead, returning a pointer type lets us safely return subclasses of the return type:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<MainWindow<State>> provideMainWindow() {
    return std::make_unique<ExampleMainWindow>();
}
```

You have further complicated matters by using templates. Templates and inheritance can combine in unexpected ways in C++. Templates are *not* generics, each template instantiation with distinct parameters leads to a distinct type. There is no relationship between `Template<A>` and `Template<B>`.

Fortunately, that will not be a large issue for your scenario.
Instead, note that you are referring to a type `State` within `App` without declaring such a type. You likely want a `template<class State> class App`. Whenever you use `App` later, you will have to supply the appropriate template argument (e.g. `ExampleMainWindowState`). If such template parameters permeate your design, this can get in the way. Sometimes, the compile-time safety of template parameters can be sacrificed, and similar behaviour modelled with inheritance and run-time checks. But without knowing the context and forces on your design, it's impossible to tell whether that could be advantageous here.